# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var' error

Tags: javascript

```
function Validate()

var username = document.getElementById("user").value;

if(username == "")
{
    alert("username must be filled")
}
```

tried this code line (new for js) for my school project but I got this weird

errorUncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'var'

any help? thanks!

Comment: You have a typo. Missing a `{` after `Validate()` and a closing `}`. Consider using a JS lint tool to quickly catch issues like this? https://eslint.org/

Comment: Check again how a function definition looks; Right now it does not have a start nor an end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your syntax is wrong. use below method

```
function Validate()
{    
    var username = document.getElementById("user").value;
    
    if(username == "")
    {
      alert("username must be filled");
    }
}
```